# C Language Switch Statement not reading full character input

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a switch statement to read a quote input by the user.  The problem I'm having is that it is only reading the first character and the program quits.  It needs to reach all characters input and measure against conditions listed.  I'm new to c language, so not at the arrays stage yet.  I just need a pointer where I'm going wrong!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int c;
    int temp = 0;
    int ch;
    int reader;

    printf("Enter 1-read from keyboard or 2-read from file\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &reader);

    switch (reader) {

    case 1:

        printf("Please enter a quote\n");//user input characters

        scanf_s("%c", &c);

        while ((c = _getch()) !='\n'){ //reads each character and checks for end of line

            printf("\n%c", c);


            if (temp == c)

                printf(" duplicate character");


            if ((c) == 'a' || (c) == 'e' || (c) == 'i' || (c) == 'o' || (c) == 'u')

                printf("  vowel is lower case");

            if ((c) == 'A' || (c) == 'E' || (c) == 'I' || (c) == 'O' || (c) == 'U')

                printf("  vowel is upper case");

            if (ispunct(c))//checks for punctuation

                printf("  punctuation");

            temp = c;
            break;

    case 2:

        printf("I need some help");
        break;

    default:



        break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So where is your loop statement?

Comment: Your `while` and your `cases` are cross-nested, that is half `case 1` and the whole `case 2:` and `default` are inside the `while` loop. Is that really your intent?

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &c);` --> `scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);`, please add a length argument and read the [man page for `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), but why are you mixing two input styles anyway?

Comment: Check @rodrigo's comment. You probably confused nesting/brackets. Make sure you close the `while` loop properly.

Comment: Remove the Windows-specifics from your code, or tag it "Windows". As presented, it's not C.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` statements are tricky... Your code is, removing the filling lines, something like this:

```
switch (reader)
{
    case 1:
        while (getch(...))
        {
            //do things
            break;  // !!!!!!
    case 2:
        break;
    default:
        break;
        }
}
```

Look at the line with the exclamation marks. You may thing that it is breaking the `switch` but it is actually breaking the `while`, so your program ends.

The solution is easy, move the `}` to the proper place, just before that line. Or even better, write a function for case 1 and another one for case 2.

Comment: Thank you :-)  Easy when you know how